# No adapter attached; skipping layout, RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I checked all answers about my problem on StackOverFlow but no one solves my problem.

I have a Fragment and init RecyclerView in the onCreateView method and nothing more.
But I still have problem.

my code:

```
private RecyclerView mStatisticView;
private StatisticAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stat, container, false);

    mStatisticView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv_stats);
    mStatisticView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mStatisticView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    adapter = new StatisticAdapter();
    List<StatisticLabel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(<Data object>);
    list.add(<Data object>);
    list.add(<Data object>);
    adapter.addItems(list);
    mStatisticView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}
```

Could you please help me, what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be worrying much about this message at all. This happens when the `RecyclerView` is in layout phase and attempts to check if in that same phase can layout also its children. So everything is laid out in one phase. After you set the adapter this message will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

In the methode onCreateView() the Activity is not finished loading, so getActivity() should return null.
This could become a problem, so try to set your things in onActivityCreated()

[image]

Comment: I checked it, getActivity() is always not null